# Google Sheets Api russian symbols at request body

Tags: api, rest, google-sheets, request

Learning how to use google sheets api v4. Trying to create spreadSheet with custom Title by request:

```
POST https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets and body:
{
    "properties":{
        "title": "АЦ Витебский"
    }
}
```

headers:

```
Authorization: "Bearer ..."
Content-type: "text/plain, charset=UTF-8"
Accept-Encoding: "gzip"
```

Problem in resulting name of spreadSheet: "?? ????????"

Trying various charsets and encodings

Use it in my spring application on java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolve this by adding MessageConverter for restTemplate

```
template.getMessageConverters()
                .add(0, new StringHttpMessageConverter(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```